# Dual os partitioning - is it possible to make connected hdd unrecognised?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Supoose that I have 2 ssd, installed with ubuntu and windows respectively, and 1 hdd for each os, configured in NTFS and FAT format.
EDIT: Sorry for having 2 questions at a time. Perhaps the second question will be answered in comment.

1. Is it possible for me to install the hard drive in some way so that ubuntu can't recognize windows hdd and vice versa?
2. If I add another hdd which accessible by windows and ubuntu, will a program like geforce nvidia driver works or I need to install for both OS respectively

Thank you for your time

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Comment: @DavidFoerster hello. I'm sorry if the thread I made has two questions. I thought that the questions are still relevant so I put it together.

Comment: As far as I understand them your two questions are about two strictly opposing situations (multiple drives with mutually inaccessible operating systems vs. multiple drives sharing data for common operating system features).

Comment: @DavidFoerster perhaps I misunderstood. Sorry then.

Answer (score 0):

Linux ubuntu can hide drives with [udev](https://wiki.debian.org/udev), the device manager for the Linux kernel.
Simply create some rules for specifying the drives you want the be hidden.

The rules must be written in a file
`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disks.rules`

For example, you want to hide drives `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb1`, the file will be:

```
# file /etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disks.rules
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
KERNEL=="sdb2", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}="1"
```